# Angular 7 Hot Reload hanging

Tags: angular, angular-material

Getting some awful build times on an application I've inherited: ~110000-150000ms. I've noticed it spends around 2 minutes of that time hanging on an early step in the process but no errors.

**50% building 0/25 modules 25 active ...terial\radio\typings\index.ngfactory.js**

I am using ahead-of-time compilation and will put the command I'm using and the Angular versioning information below.

```
node ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.6
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

It appears to be some issue between the compiler, material and the aot compilation. I'm just not sure where to start researching or debugging. I found a few similar issue with Angular 6 and aot but those builds were outright failing and that issue was fixed in Angular 6. I really need to nail down why this is hanging and get these build times down for my team's sake. Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this question is too broad, many causes are possible, we can't have a look to your whole app to find the problem...

Comment: I know it may be difficult to pinpoint the exact cause here but I feel I have narrowed it down significantly. I suspect it has to be an issue with material and the aot compilation, something surely someone has encountered before if that's the case.

Comment: @ChrisCastor still, there can be any number of reasons. if you can provide a zip replacating same issue. Then maybe we can help.

Comment: Yeah I tried replicating it with a fresh angular app with those same dependencies but couldn't recreate it. Not so sure it's material related anymore. Webpack seems to be doing some funky things with this application's modules. The first save in an unchanged file seemed to recompile the module, the second save recompiled all but 24 of the app's modules, after that it correctly identified all 149 chunks as unchanged. Not sure why it hangs on the material modules like that but there's more going on here for sure.

Comment: when compilation is stuck, do not trust the module being logged. It may be a random module, not related to the problem. It often comes from a import loop, or something like this. It may be an import in a file, an import in a css file... anything... You may try to remove some modules from you app, and check when it stops being stuck... and then re-import the modules one by one...

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far! I found a "shared" module of 90+ components being imported into 66 modules, I think that might be some of the cause of the slowness. They also created a fairly large MaterialModule and imported that into just as many modules. Even the smallest module on this application contains well over 100 imports. [link](https://i.imgur.com/Y5SYWIY.png)